# How data adapter is disconnected architecture as it is using data reader to fill datatable?

Tags: c#, ado.net, datareader, dataadapter

I am trying to understand data adapter and 1 thing i understand that data adapter internally uses data reader to fill datatable.

Source : https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/Common/DataAdapter.cs

If this is true then how data adapter is disconnected architecture because after loading all data in to datatable,data adapter will close the connection.

Answer (score 1):

It's called disconnected architecture because once you have your `DataSet` / `DataTable` filled, you no longer need to be connected to the database, as apposed to using a `DataReader` that requires an open connection to the database.

This means that you don't need an open connection to the database while you are working on the data - instead you only open the connection when you need to load data from the database or send data to the database (using the DataAdapter's `SelectCommand`, `InsertCommand`, `UpdateCommand` and `DeleteCommand`)

Comment: That i agree data reader requires an open connection but the thing is if dataadapter itself uses data reader behind the scenes which requires an open connection to the database right.So that means till data reader have fill up datatable connection will remain open so how it is disconnected architecture because it also requires open connection till datatable is filled

Comment: @User You're going to have to connect to your database at some point to send/receive data. With DataAdapter you don't have to stay connected to use the DataSet returned. With DataReader you do.

Comment: @JonathonChase So while dataadapter is filling datatable,is there any load on database server?

Comment: @User You have to be connected to the database in order to get or update data... While these actions takes place, there is some load on the database and network between the database and software. How big is that load depends on how much data there is and how well it is stored and indexed.